# PHP, Generating Primes, What's Wrong

Tags: php

What's wrong with this? The conditional statement looks solid enough, yet all numbers are included

```
function generate_primes(){
   $max = 100;
   $primes = array();

   for($current_pointer = 1; $current_pointer <= $max; $current_pointer++){

        for($divider = 1; $divider <= $current_pointer; $divider++){
        //if(in_array($divider, $primes)){
        if(($current_pointer % $divider === 0) && ($divider !== 1) && ($divider ===    $current_pointer)){
           $primes[] = $current_pointer;
           }
//}

        }

    }
print_r($primes);

}
generate_primes();
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: You can make this slightly more efficient by starting your loops at 2, which eliminates the check for "are we testing 1", and given that 2 is the only even prime, you can even start your loops at 3. Then, because other than 2 (which you've eliminated), there's no way any evens can be a divisor, you can increment your loops by 2 at each iteration.

Comment: I gonna need a coffee right now :-)

Comment: Well in my next attempt I would test only by the accumulated primes, that would make it more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deal with the case that your divider does divide evenly into your current_pointer but the divider doesn't equal the current pointer.  In that case, you need to jump out of the loop (i.e. you've found something that divides evenly, so the number isn't prime).  As written, all loops eventually hit the case of dividing the number by itself, so all numbers succeed.

In other words, you're trying to test for the FIRST successful divider being the number itself, but to do that, you have to stop trying when you hit a different successful divider.

```
    if(($current_pointer % $divider === 0) && ($divider !== 1)){
         if ($divider === $current_pointer)
            $primes[] = $current_pointer;
         } else {
            continue; // the continue makes you stop testing the current pointer and go on to the next
         }
```

Comment: I marked this correct, because it accurately describes the problem, yet follows my line of reasoning, thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Re-think your algorithm. A prime number is *a natural number > 1 that is not evenly divisible by any other natural number except itself and 1*. So, if `$current_pointer % $divider === 0`, the number in question can't be a prime number, becauseit is divisible by `$divider`. So why do you add it to the array?

**Edit in response to comments:** To clarify, this means that you have to check for *all* possible divisors (from 2 to the number itself -1) and make sure that *not a single* of them divides the number in question without a remainder. In and *only this case* the number is a prime.

You can optimize this algorithm slightly (i.e. the root of your number can be the upper bound for the inner loop), but first try to get things working in the basic case.

Comment: He's trying to test that the only even divider is the number itself (or 1).

Comment: Ah, thanks - that's the intent. I really wondered. Well, it doesn't change the response: rethink what a prime is and how you check for it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your last condition should be:

```
$divider !== $current_pointer
```

Comment: But  I do mean `$divider === $current_pointer`, Only if the smallest dividing integer is equal to the numerator, it is going to be a prime, isn't it?

Comment: I think you should look at Alexander Gessler's advice.

Comment: Yes, but in your current algorithm, if you hit a smaller dividing integer, you keep going, so you aren't necessarily getting the smallest one.

Answer (score 1):

Two wrong things: 1) `$divider === $current_pointer)` should be `$divider != $current_pointer)` and 2) you are adding the number to the $primes array after each and every iteration.

Suggestions: 1) start the second loop by 2, since you want $divider not to be 1 in the first place, and 2) make $divider < $current_pointer (instead of <=), since you also want $divider not to be itself.

Try this:

```
function generate_primes(){    
    $max = 100;    
    $primes = array();    

    for($current_pointer = 1; $current_pointer <= $max; $current_pointer++){   

        $prime = true;  

        for($divider = 2; $divider < $current_pointer; $divider++){         

            if($current_pointer % $divider == 0) $prime = false;

        } 
        if($prime == true) array_push($primes, $current_pointer);
    } 
    print_r($primes);  
} 

generate_primes();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your loop is a bit funny ;)  If you want to exclude 1, don't start with 1

Second, I don't understand the last clause of your conditional.  You are saying you will only consider it a prime if the divider is === to current pointer.  I think you mean != to current pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your if statement.  It essentially says:

Mark a number as prime if:

1. current_pointer equals 0.
2. divider doesn't equal 0.
3. divider equals current_pointer.

The only time all 3 of those conditionals will be true is when the final conditional is true (divider equals current_pointer.)

If the current pointer is 6, then when the divider equals 6, you'll store it as a prime (obviously not true.)

See this example as a simple (although expensive implementation) function for testing if a number is prime (you could easily use the logic to make a generator.)
[Prime number checker](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2638.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
if( ($current_pointer % $divider === 0) && 
    ($divider !== 1) && 
    ($divider === $current_pointer)){
```

will ***always be true*** when `$divider == $current_pointer`

A better approach is to use a `is_prime` flag initiated to true. Set it to false if any number smaller than it divides it.

A further enhancement would be to add the number two, and then only check non even numbers.

```
   function generate_primes($max = 100){    
        $primes = array(2);    

        for($current_pointer = 3; $current_pointer <= $max; $current_pointer += 2){   
            if(is_odd_number_a_prime($current_pointer)){
                $primes[] = $current_pointer;
        } 
        print_r($primes);  
        return $primes
    } 

    function is_odd_number_a_prime($n){
      if(is_int($n)){
            for($divider = 3; $divider < $n; $divider +=2 ){             
                if($current_pointer % $n == 0){
                    return false;
                }
            } 

      }else{
        return false;
      }     
      return true;
    }

   $primes = generate_primes();
```

You could further enhance things by using a sieve.

Comment: @Sid Kunte I do not understand your comment - unless you mean that the three conditionals are the definition of a prime - However, the problem with that is you are not rejecting numbers when the first two conditions pass and the current_pointer is not the divider. You need to reverse your logic. Instead of accepting based on one condition, accept to begin with and reject based on one condition (that should not be met) being met.

Comment: Yes, I finally solved it (in pseudocode) if the divider divides evenly, but is less than the current_pointer, it is not a prime, break out of loop; but if the divider is equal to the current_pointer and we have not found smaller even dividers, then current_pointer must a prime

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look up the Sieve of Eratosthene algorithm. It's for getting a list of primes, and is very fast compared to the brute force approach you are taking. While your code will run fine for smaller numbers, you'll find as you try to, for example, get all primes < 10,000,000 it will take a long time.

Comment: Wow! I will next try to write a program that does just that. The [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)